# App works in android emulator but not on the phone

Tags: android, android-logcat

I get "Unfortunately, app is stopped" message when i tried to open the app on the phone. App works fine on the emulator. With Logcat listed below, I can't seem to find anything that is an error concerning my Breakeven app.  Can someone please help?  Thanks.

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3344K, 32% free 11674K/17104K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 231K, 30% free 11992K/17104K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 32ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 307K, 29% free 12303K/17104K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 26ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 466K, 27% free 12602K/17104K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 48ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 40ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 534K, 25% free 12981K/17104K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 21ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 603K, 22% free 13370K/17104K, paused 6ms+2ms, total 25ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1054K, 22% free 13454K/17104K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 23ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 762K, 20% free 13832K/17104K, paused 4ms+1ms, total 21ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 538K, 18% free 14143K/17104K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
D/AbsListView(31894): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2995K, 31% free 12083K/17344K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 27% free 12747K/17344K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 19ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 22% free 13659K/17344K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1585K, 21% free 14667K/18484K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1297K, 20% free 14800K/18484K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
D/AbsListView(31894): onDetachedFromWindow
W/InputEventReceiver(31894): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
W/InputEventReceiver(31894): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
W/ViewRootImpl(31894): Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=440.0, y[0]=-101.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=20709840, downTime=20709831, deviceId=6, source=0x1002 }
E/ViewRootImpl(31894): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1898K, 23% free 14347K/18484K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1304K, 22% free 14518K/18484K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 17ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 79K, 22% free 14518K/18484K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(31894): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.374MB for 426256-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 21% free 14934K/18904K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3790K, 30% free 14774K/20816K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1495K, 29% free 14823K/20816K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 27ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1682K, 30% free 14684K/20816K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 28ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1260K, 29% free 14971K/20816K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 21ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1713K, 29% free 14836K/20816K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1601K, 30% free 14766K/20816K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1676K, 30% free 14634K/20816K, paused 5ms+1ms, total 23ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1397K, 29% free 14783K/20816K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 28ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 24ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1409K, 28% free 15013K/20816K, paused 4ms+1ms, total 21ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4483K, 42% free 12190K/20816K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 34ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 38% free 12940K/20816K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 20ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 34% free 13920K/20816K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 22ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3357K, 34% free 13818K/20816K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 321K, 29% free 14796K/20816K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 41ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 23ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1518K, 21% free 14864K/18596K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 16ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1004K, 18% free 15341K/18596K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1494K, 20% free 15341K/18972K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1753K, 22% free 14949K/18972K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1292K, 21% free 15165K/18972K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 698K, 18% free 15639K/18972K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1280K, 20% free 15505K/19264K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onDetachedFromWindow
E/ViewRootImpl(31894): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AbsListView(31894): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onDetachedFromWindow
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5286K, 38% free 12000K/19264K, paused 8ms+10ms, total 62ms
D/AbsListView(31894): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
I/MotionRecognitionManager(31894):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,  
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
I/MotionRecognitionManager(31894):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,  
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): onDetachedFromWindow
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
E/ViewRootImpl(31894): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/dalvikvm(31894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 836K, 38% free 11759K/18740K, paused 23ms+4ms, total 62ms
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(31894): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Comment: Are the phone and emulator running the same android version?

Comment: Look for a stacktrace in your logcat. The logcat you provided doesn't contain one.

Comment: The app did run on the phone before until I made changes.  That was all there was in the logcat.

Comment: Are you filtering your logcat? If so, don't. You'll miss important/valuable information.

Comment: I didn't put any filters in, well, not that I'm consciously aware of doing.

Comment: I changed the preferences on the phone in different ways and still get no errors on Logcat.  Any other ideas?